# ¿Cómo puedo hacer mi método de ordenamiento shaker en modo ascendente? Solo lo tengo descendente

Tags: java, array, netbeans, método

```
public  void ordenacionShaker(int[] v) {
    final int N = v.length;
    int limInferior = 0;
    int limSuperior = N-1;
    while(limInferior <= limSuperior) {
        for(int j=limInferior; j<limSuperior; j++) {
            if(v[j]>v[j+1]) {
                int tmp = v[j];
                v[j]    = v[j+1];
                v[j+1]  = tmp;
            }
        }
        limSuperior--;
        for(int j=limSuperior;j>limInferior; j--) {
            if(v[j]<v[j-1]) {
                int tmp = v[j];
                v[j]    = v[j-1];
                v[j-1]  = tmp;
            }
        }
        limInferior++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta invirtiendo los operadores ">" "<" en tus condiciones si tienes un ">" cambialo por un "<" y viceversa.